# How To Create Dynamic Json for Form set and get values and bind to display the values?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic 3 and creating a page without validation that redirect's to other page and display's the data and it's not happening please help me..!

Want's to create a dynamic json and want's to show on other page these data..!

`public user = [`
`{`
`full_name:'',`
`phone:,`
`alt:,`
`pincode:,`
 `address:' ',`
`locality:'',`
`landmark:' ',`
`city:'',`
`state:'',`
`country:'',`
`radio:''`
`}`
 `];`

how to set and get the values and show the data to other page regarding entered values in the form with the help of ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get data from inputs like this in `.html` file.

```
<ion-input placeholder="Name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputFieldValue"></ion-input>
```

Then in `.ts` file you have value like this.

```
public inputFieldValue;
console.log("--------inputFieldValue-------",inputFieldValue)
```

and after this you have to make a json object of that data like this.

```
let data = {
   key:this.inputFieldValue
}
```

and pass it in the next page using `NavController`.

```
this.navCtrl.push(page_name_you_want_to_redirect,data)
```

and fetch it in the second page using `NavParams`

```
this.navParams.get("data")
```

Thats it!
You get your data in the second page wherever you want.

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: specific of the console.log(); in that ; is missing and when i am entering it it's not properly returning me back..

Comment: mustufa i have checkout.ts file where i created the code below :public user = [ { full_name:'', phone:, alt:, pincode:, address:' ', locality:'', landmark:' ', city:'', state:'', country:'', radio:'' } ]; and all i want is that data to address page...

Comment: I think the problem is where you create a json.

Comment: mustufa please it's urgent will let me know how to do that code..?how to let the shopping page display the data regarding checkout page entered the data from ionic 3

Comment: I think you have to pass your data in this way : `[{
 "full_name": "dijscssa",
 "phone": "+91885616622",
 "alt": "waaw",
 "pincode": "356864",
 "address": "asassassa",
 "locality": "asssas",
 "landmark": "sasass",
 "city": "ssazassas",
 "state": "sxssx",
 "country": "ssaxsax",
 "radio": "sxsaxsax"
}]`

that is correct format.

Comment: yes for sure but i have to take the dynamic values from the user and show that values to other page which is shopping page which i have to put it on other page

Comment: did you had done it? if yes then did you had logged it?

Comment: no just let me know what to do ...?
i have the shopping page and checkout page 
where the checkout page i have taken as the data inputed from the user and all the data should be displaying to other page shopping page while entered in the checkoutpage..?

Comment: i haven't done before but yes what you gave me i tried it,and not happening is there another way too do the dynamic json form form in ionic 3..?

Comment: can you share your code? on any platform which you want

Comment: give me your mail..!

Comment: mustafa.mscit15@gmail.com

Comment: mustufa can i know how much time it will take..?

Comment: @mustufa can i know how to display that data.. in console undefined data is comming.??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an object without values or definitions, you must assign a value, at least "null":

```
public user = [ { full_name:'', phone:null, alt:null, pincode:null,  address:' ', locality:'', landmark:' ', city:'', state:'', country:'', radio:'' }  ];
```

Other cause of problems maybe the "Array"... why? do you need an array? or just an object? You are defining an Array of Objects!!! I would suggest you just do:

```
    public user = {full_name:'', phone:null, alt:null, pincode:null,  address:' ', locality:'', landmark:' ', city:'', state:'', country:'', radio:'' };
```

and then pass it using the NavCtrl that Mustafa told you...

Comment: i had done as he said please let me know more about what to do for bind the data ..? to other page..?